# can't linearly independent vectors form a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

since linearly independent systems are not collinear with the origin does that mean a set of linearly independent vectors can't form a subspace? I'm not sure if my question makes sense.

Comment: "*the*" set of linearly independent vectors.  Which set of many possible sets is "*the*" set?  Which scalar field?  If you have some vector $v$ in your space and you have some elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the scalar field, are $\alpha v$ and $\beta v$ in your space?

Comment: If x and y are linearly independent then {x,y,x+y} isnt. So, the answer is No.

Comment: A subspace must always include the zero vector. Any set that includes the zero vector is linearly *dependent*.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for the reply. so I am going to assume $\alpha v$ and $\beta v$ are not in my set.

Comment: @zaza:  then your set is not a subspace

Comment: The singular definite article **the** indicates a specific, distinguished, set. So when you say "the set of linearly independent vectors" you are implying that there is a specific, special set we can identify by those words. There isn't such a set, so you should not use the singular definite article. You should use the indefinite article **a**. "Does that mean that **a** set of linearly independent vectors cannot form a subspace?"

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see what you are saying. Thank you for the explanation I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that no linearly independent set of vectors may form a subspace; "collinearity" is more of a geometric concept and not all vector spaces have easy geometric interpretation, though...

The simplest way to note your desired conclusion, in my opinion, it the one I indicated in the comments: every subspace must include the zero vector, but any set of vectors that includes the zero vector is necessarily linearly dependent. So the collection of all vectors in a subspace is *always* linearly dependent.

By contrapositive, if a set is linearly *independent*, then it cannot be "the set of all vectors in a subspace", and so cannot be a subspace.